# Builder annotates a private class?

Tags: java, lombok

```
@Data
@Builder
public class ClassA {
    private ClassB b;
    private String createdBy;
    private class ClassB {
        String name;
        int version;
    }
}
```

Hi I want to create ClassA in another java file this way:

```
ClassA.builder().createdBy("Alex")
                .b(ClassB.builder()
                         .name("Game")
                         .version(2).build())
                .build();
```

Is this possible for private class `classB`?

Thx

Comment: Well if `ClassB` is private, you cannot write `ClassB.builder()...` in another file, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend as below:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class ClassA {
    private ClassB b;
    private String createdBy;
    @Builder
    @Data
    static class ClassB {
       String name;
       int version;
   }
}
```

if you want unvisible ClassB it is impossible. and To using `@Builder` on inner class , class must be static class

Answer (score 1):

`private` modifier means that the variable is only visible for this class only. So if you create `private class B` inside `class A` it means B only visible for A.

As @sweeper said in the comment, you cannot use `class B` in another file / class except for `class A`.

If you still want to use that way, you can create class B independently.

ClassA.class

```
@Data
@Builder
public class ClassA {
    private ClassB b;
    private String createdBy;
}
```

ClassB.class

```
@Data
@Builder
class ClassB {
    String name;
    int version;
}
```